# booting problem after dual booting installation

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I installed ubuntu 20.04 on window 10 for dual booting.
After installing, my first boot failed.
Does anyone know what the causes are?
[image]

Comment: There are plenty of answered questions on here for boot issues. Just search with “boot issue” or similar. Some boot problems can be solved using this tool https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair/

Comment: Thanks for the comment!